# Xcode is forcing me to unwrap a value that is not optional

Tags: swift, firebase, option-type

I am creating a basic blog app using Swift and Firebase to practice my programming skills.

Here's my user model:

```
class UserProfile {
    var uid: String
    var username: String
    var photoURL: URL
    init(uid: String, username: String, photoURL: URL){
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = username
        self.photoURL = photoURL
    }
}
```

Here's the chunk of code that xcode is giving me errors in:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let line = line {
            ImageService.downloadImageFrom(url: self.line?.author.photoURL, completion: { (image) in
                self.imageView.image = image
            }) // The error is in this line.
            self.username.text = line.author.username
            self.park.text = line.park
            self.attraction.text = line.attraction
            self.timestamp.text = line.createdAt.calendarTimeNow()
        }
    }
```

As you have noticed, the 'photoURL' attribute of the 'UserProfile' class is not an Optional. Xcode is requiring me to use (self.line?.author.photoURL)! to force unwrap this value that is not an Optional. What might be happening? What am I missing?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `photoURL`. The problem is that despite properly unwrapping the optional property `line`, you mistakenly attempt to use the still optional `self.line`. Because that is optional, `self.line?.author.photoURL` as a whole is optional.

Simply change `self.line?.author.photoURL` to `line.author.photoURL`.